# Handling \n and \t in exec() - Java

Tags: java, linux, exec, sybase

I'm trying to execute a bcp command like below in linux using java:

```
bcp  dbname..mytable in /home/guest/test -U guest -P guest -S LXXDB1D06 -I /opt/sybase/08/interfaces -c -Y -t \| -r \\n
```

In Java Class, I do as:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p;
try {
        p = rt.exec("bcp  dbname..mytable in /home/guest/test -U guest -P guest -S LXXDB1D06 -I /opt/sybase/08/interfaces -c -Y -t \| -r \\n");
p.waitFor();
} catch(..){

..}
```

I tried with \|, "\"+"\n" and other few. 
But didnt work. 
What should be the correct format?

Edit: With ProcessBuilder, it looks like:

```
[bcp, pfactdbcpusdev01..gb_inactive_upc, in, C:\hs_data_dev_00\itm_mstr\tmp\usaupcinact_tmp_rollup, -U, inactupcUSD1, -P, inac01, -S, ACNLNXQ002D01, -I, C:\Program Files\Nielsen\Sybase\12.5.1/interfaces, -c, -t, |, -r, \n, -Y]
```

Comment: Don't use Runtime.exec(), use a `ProcessBuilder`...

Comment: @fge I tried with processbuilder too. if I use processBuilder, how should I use \| and \\n? Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a super classical problem and I'm frankly astonished that you didn't find the solution by googling around...

The solution is to use a `ProcessBuilder`:

```
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bcp", "dbname..mytable",
    "in", "/home/guest/test",
    "-U", "guest", 
    "-P", "guest",
    "-S", "LXXDB1DO6",
    "-I", "/opt/sybase/08/interfaces",
    "-c",
    "-Y",
    "-t", "|",
    "-r", "\\n"
);
final Process p = pb.start();
```

Also, you should check the result of .waitFor().

Also check the manpage for `execve(2)`, `execl(2)` and friends.